# .ashx file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

What is an `.ashx` file in asp.net?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an ***ASP.Net web handler*** file.

Read [Generic Handlers (ASHX Files)](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_%28ASHX_Files%29.html)

[What is an ASHX file Handler or web handler?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/ASHXfileHandler03272009023910AM/ASHXfileHandler.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's for an ASP.NET *handler* as opposed to a page. For example, I use handlers to respond to Google Wave requests in my [.NET Robot API](http://code.google.com/p/wave-robot-net-client/wiki/GettingStarted).